# OSX "ld": how to show mangled names of unresolved symbols? how to get a map file?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, ld, libc++

<s>On OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion), I'm trying to link a program using libc++ (not libstdc++) and `ld` is giving me an unresolved symbol error.</s>

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::operator=(char const*)", referenced from:
      bool process_load_commands<mytype_t>(unsigned char*, ...) in module_mach_o.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

<s>This appears to be referring to the codegen for the following line:</s>

```
mystdstring = ::std::string(mycharpointer + myint);
```

<s>If I change this to</s>

```
mystdstring = mycharpointer + myint;
```

<s>then everything works fine, because we stop using the move-constructor and start using a non-move assignment operator.</s>

I'm trying to track this down, but I'm hampered by the lack of my traditional tools. Two questions come immediately to mind:

- How do I get `ld` to produce a map file? None of `-map` `-Map` `-Wl,-map=foo` `-Wl,-Map=foo` work with this linker.

  ```
  @(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-134.9
  configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64
  LTO support using: LLVM version 3.1svn, from Apple Clang 4.1 (build 421.11.65)
  ```
- How do I get `ld` to show me the un-demangled names of the unresolved C++ symbols, so I can grep the map/nm file easily?

<s>And of course if anyone has seen this particular error before and knows how to fix it, I'll accept those answers as well. :)</s>

EDIT: I realize that what I wrote above about move constructors makes no sense, because the symptom changed in the middle of my writing this question. :P I'll fix it whenever I get a better idea of what's going on.

EDIT #2: The bug disappeared. I'm tentatively blaming our self-built libc++: my best guess is that it didn't have *any* symbols in it (due to building for the wrong arch), and we just got really lucky that we never tried to use any non-inline functions except for this one.

My questions about `-map` and showing mangled names are still open, though.

Answer (score 1):

To have clang display mangled symbol names for the unresolved symbols list, use the linker/compiler flags:

```
-Xlinker --no-demangle
```

Answer (score 0):

In the libc++ `<string>` header, `basic_string::operator=(const char*)` is declared/defined as:

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY basic_string& operator=(const_pointer __s) {return assign(__s);}
```

_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY is a macro that expands to "always inline" and "mark hidden".  Therefore this member function should always be inlined and the linker should never be looking for it.

Have you by chance changed the definition of the _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY macro?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea. It's possible. We build our own libc++, and the build process is impenetrable. :P But see above (which I've just now updated): after a few hours of jiggling the handle, the original linker error vanished on its own.

Comment: Its amazing how often jiggling the handle fixes the problem. :-)